# Regex help in Grunt and Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use regex to dynamically change a version number in JavaScript using Grunt text replace.

My code looks like this:

```
version: {
    src: '../jsp/thirdparty/us/common/trackjs_tags.jsp',
    regex: /\bversion:\"\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\"$/,
    replacement: 'version:"<%= pkg.version %>"'
  }
```

And I'm trying to match this:

```
version:"1.1.1"
```

Here is [my regex](https://regex101.com/r/8xA8k9/1) that works.

However, when I try in Grunt, it isn't catching it and I don't know why. Any help would be appreciated!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
/\bversion:\"\b\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\"/g,
```

It needed a g at the end instead of a dollar sign!